# How to run cron for every 2 minute but start at 5th minute of a specific hour?

Tags: kubernetes, cron, cron-task, kubernetes-cronjob

Basically my cron is updating database every 2 minutes. But I need to run another cron which updates database every 24 hour. I need to make sure there are no race condition while the second cron (per day) is running i.e, both the cron can not run together and overlap. This needs to be implemented in Kubernetes cluster using jobs. 
My solution is to run the first cron every 2 minutes but delay by 5 minutes when second cron runs (per day). 
Any alternative solution is welcomed.

Comment: How much time it takes for these jobs to complete? Running every 2 minutes would be `*/2 * * * *` and every 24h would be `0 0 * * *` (every midnight). After setting it up, you can create a script that checks the time and if time is equal midnight, you make it sleep for some time before running it. If it looks like a solution for you, let me know and I can create an answer with more details.

Comment: Have you checked my answer, let me know if it helped you and consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to think about few possibilities but things can go wrong mainly by the fact that you have a job that is required to run every 2 minutes and let's suppose your daily job for any reason takes more time than you expect, a new 2 min job will start and this can't happen.

The best possible solution would be to solve this in a code level. You could create a lock in your application to prevent these jobs from running at the same time.

If you really can't come up with any solution to solve this problem in your code, there is a mechanism on Kubernetes that prevents a new job from the same cronjob to start. You can set the flag [spec.concurrencyPolicy:  Forbid](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) so if your job takes longer than 2 minutes to start, the new job will be skipped. This is not a global flag, this is per cronjob only.

You can aggregate this possibility with [spec.initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) and find a way to run both tasks in the same cronjob.

spec.initContainers are specialized containers that run before app containers.

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          initContainers
          - name: hello1
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          containers:
          - name: hello2
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - DATE=`date +"%H:%M"`; if [[ $DATE == "00:00" ]]; then date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster; fi
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

This manifest is defining a cronJob that will run every 2 minutes and will start a initContainer (your 2 min job) and will also run a second container every 2 minutes. The thing is that in this second container we have a shell script checking if it's midnight (ignored the seconds as we can't be sure when it will start).

You may have to tune this part of the code:

```
DATE=`date +"%H:%M"; if [[ $DATE == "00:00" ]
```

Let's suppose your first container takes more than a minute to execute, it'll be 00:01 and your second job will never be executed.

Let me know if these information and solution helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cron for time like */2 * * * * and 0 1 * * * and when you start running your code at any even instance of time it will never clash.

This helps to solve the problem at logic level and does not need any additional code attention.
because it will run the 2nd cron at 12:01 everyday and the first cron will be running at even minute instances which will never coincide with with each other

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

with **schedule: "5/2 * * * *"** , you can get configuration here
[https://crontab.guru/#5/2_*_*****](https://crontab.guru/#5/2_*_*_*_*) also with a speciic hour. I suggest to verify also timezone and securityContext. Here an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: ns
  name: nameCronJob
spec:
  timeZone: "Europe/Rome"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 1800
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: "5/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            runAsGroup: 2000
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
          containers:
          - image: <repo>/<image>:<tag>
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: namejob_container
            command: ["/bin/bash","-c","script.sh"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).